# How to handle multi tenancy with SLIM?

Tags: php, database, api, slim, multi-tenant

I'm writing an `API` using [SLIM](http://www.slimframework.com/), the goal of that API is create a multi tenant structure. What I did so far is the following:

First of all, I have created a **master** database which contains all my customers (who bought my software), for each customer I have a field called `CUSTOMER_TOKEN`, which represents the credentials to access to the API.

Basically, I have two software here:

- API: read the data from the tenant database.
- Main application: use the API.

Infact, each tenant have a different database, I find this way the best choice for me.

Main application get a `JWT` token sending a request to the `API` by using the `CUSTOMER_TOKEN`, eg:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/auth/login
```

the route above will check the customer existence on the **master** database, if exists, then will return a temporary access token to use the `API` (JWT).

So far all good. The main problem come's here. Infact, if the user has got the `JWT` and the `CUSTOMER_TOKEN` is valid, then the `API` should create a connection to the `tenant` database rather than the **master** database.

At the moment, for handle the main connection, I use the `SLIM` container, in particular:

```
<?php
   use Slim\Container;

   $container = $app->getContainer();

   $container['pdo'] = function (Container $c) {
       $db = $c['settings']['db'];
        $pdo = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";dbname=" . $db['dbname'],
            $db['user'],
            $db['pass']
        );
        return $pdo;
    };
```

how can I create a different connection to the tenant database from here? Should I use a `middleware`? Should I check the requested router to understand if I need the master db or tenant db?

Take as note that for each tenant I use a name convention structure such as:

```
app_name-tenant-tenant_name
```

So I have the prefix as `app_name-tenant` and then the `tenant_name`. So I only need to get the name of the `customer` from the **master** db to assemble the connection.

How would you manage this situation? thank you.

Comment: Is the question about having multiple (2) database connections in combination with a container?

Comment: Hi @odan yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security and practical reasons I would recommend using two different PDO connections (instances). The first connection is for the API (JWT) Auth and the second database connection is for the customer (tenant). You don't need a middleware, because the database connection part of the infrastructure configuration and below the middleware.

You have multiple options to manage the database connections in combination with a container.

1. Just add a second alias name for the container entry like `pdo2` or `db2` or someting similar that makes sense for you.

```php
// API
$container['pdo'] = function (Container $container) {
```

```php
// Customer database
$container['pdo2'] = function (Container $container) {
```

2. I hope you use [constructor dependency injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html). If yes, better define the container entries with a class or the interface name.

Example:

```php
class ApiDatabase extends PDO {}

$container[ApiDatabase::class] = function (Container $container) {
```

```php
class CustomerDatabase extends PDO {}

$container[CustomerDatabase::class] = function (Container $container) {
```

> name convention

Now you have a second database connection for the customer, a table prefix is no longer necessary because you already have a technically better separation between the customers. Why? Database transactions are also completely separated, which has no effect on other customer data (and tables). Database migrations will be easier because you don't have to worry about prefixes. Now you can deploy new versions per customer without affecting other customers' database.